# Applying `nth-of-type` to a certain class doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need light-blue lines, **starting from 2nd** (!) to have a `margin-top` parameter. Based on the code below, line *Example_1* stays as it is, while *Example_2*, *Example_3* ... *Example_999* **do** have a `margin-top`.
Light-blue lines are `example` class, but `ol > li::span.example::nth-of-type(n+2)` is not working for some reason.
What am i doing wrong in implementation of the `example` class to the `nth-of-type(n+2)` logic?
As you can see, i have **2** *independent* ordered lists here (**#1** is 1, 2, 3 and **#2** is just 1). I need the above-mentioned `nth-of-type` logic to work in both lists of course.

```css
.meaning {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #1f2c60;
  margin: 0 1vw 0 1vw;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: mycounter;
  padding-left: 2.3em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: mycounter;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-bottom: 0.6%;
  --size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  line-height: calc(var(--size) + 0.5em);
}

ol>li::before {
  content: counter(mycounter);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1f2c60;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0.045em 0.045em 0.07em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  --size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  left: calc(-1 * var(--size) - 0.5em);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: var(--size);
  font-size: calc(var(--size) - 0.3em);
}

ol>li::span.example::nth-of-type(n+2) {
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.example {
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
  color: #5d78e5;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.example_translated {
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
  color: #4b5ea7;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="meaning">
  <ol>
    <li>Meaning_1</li>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="example">Example_1</span></li>
      <li><span class="example_translated">Example_Translated_1</span></li>
    </ul>
    <li>Meaning_2</li>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="example">Example_2</span></li>
      <li><span class="example_translated">Example_Translated_2</span></li>
    </ul>
    <li>Meaning_3</li>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="example">Example_3</span></li>
      <li><span class="example_translated">Example_Translated_3</span></li>
    </ul>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="meaning">
  <ol>
    <li>Meaning_1</li>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="example">Example_1</span></li>
      <li><span class="example">Example_2</span></li>
      <li><span class="example">Example_3</span></li>
    </ul>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean, just looking at your title, the problem is clear. It's `:nth-of-type` not `:nth-of-class`.

Comment: Element 'ul' cannot be nested inside element 'ol'

Comment: :nth-of-type is pseudo class not pseudo element 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: @Dmitry Kolchev You mean I should wrap `ul` in `li` like explained here, i suppose? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398330/nesting-a-ul-inside-an-ol

Comment: @HexenSage Yes, permitted content of <ul> or <ol> elements are zero or more <li>, <script> and <template> elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to erase the `span`elements inside the `li`s and apply the `.example` class directly to the `li` elements. Then you can use `li.example:not(:first-child)`as a selector.

Note: `span` elements are inline by default, so you can't apply a margin-top to them.

```css
.meaning {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #1f2c60;
  margin: 0 1vw 0 1vw;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: mycounter;
  padding-left: 2.3em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: mycounter;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-bottom: 0.6%;
  --size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  line-height: calc(var(--size) + 0.5em);
}

ol>li::before {
  content: counter(mycounter);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1f2c60;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0.045em 0.045em 0.07em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  --size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  left: calc(-1 * var(--size) - 0.5em);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: var(--size);
  font-size: calc(var(--size) - 0.3em);
}

ol>li::span.example::nth-of-type(n+2) {
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.example {
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
  color: #5d78e5;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.example_translated {
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
  color: #4b5ea7;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}
li.example:not(:first-child)  {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #faa;
}
```

```html
<div class="meaning">
  <ol>
    <li>Meaning_1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="example">Example_1</li>
      <li class="example_translated">Example_Translated_1</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Meaning_2</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="example">Example_2</li>
      <li class="example_translated">Example_Translated_2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Meaning_3</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="example">Example_3</li>
      <li class="example_translated">Example_Translated_3</li>
    </ul>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="meaning">
  <ol>
    <li>Meaning_1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="example">Example_1</li>
      <li class="example">Example_2</li>
      <li class="example">Example_3</li>
    </ul>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation that you are doing now has no sense, but you are close.

```
ol > ul:nth-of-type(n+2) li span.example {
  margin-top: 3%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

This is what you are searching for.
Reading from the right to left this means:

*take all the span with the class example that are inside a li that is inside a ul starting from the second ul that is a direct son of a ol*

I added a background color to make it more visible, try this in your code and tell me.

Comment: I replaced my `ol>li::span.example::nth-of-type(n+2)` with your `ol > ul:nth-of-type(n+2) li span.example` and nothing has changed. Did i misunderstand you somehow? Explanation with reading from right to left is very helpful though - especially for beginners like me.